# ASP MVC 5 FilterConfig for custom exception with view in subfolder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to catch exceptions of my custom type `MissingSettingException`, and show a custom error page.

I am using FilterConfig to specify the view to display:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute
        {
            ExceptionType = typeof(MissingSettingException),
            View = "MissingSetting",
            Order = 2
        });
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

This works if I keep the view file `MissingSetting.cshtml` inside my project in `~/Views/Shared`, but I have multiple custom error pages and would rather keep them in a subfolder at `~/Views/Error/...`.

If I move `MissingSetting.cshtml` to my preferred location, I can't figure out how to get my filter to show the right view.  I will get an error page saying "An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.".  I've tried:

- `View = "MissingSetting"` (no change)
- `View = "~/Error/MissingSetting"`
- `View = "~/Error/MissingSetting.cshtml"`
- `View = "~Error/MissingSetting"`
- `View = "~Error/MissingSetting.cshtml"`

What are the magic words?

Comment: magic word is `RazorViewEngine`. You can override it to specify where to look for views: http://theshravan.net/blog/configure-the-views-search-locations-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Here is the source code, so you know what it does by default and how to override: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/RazorViewEngine.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

- Put my errors views in `~/Views/Shared/Errors`
- Change my filter definition to use `View = "Errors/MissingSetting"`

I've searched enough that it's possible my eyes glazed over, but I didn't find any clue that it's possible to keep my error views folder in the site root, or anywhere outside of `~/Views/Shared`.  At least they can be contained in a subfolder.

Still curious about alternate solutions if anyone wants to share.